# JavaScript How to delete key from copied object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have query object

```
var q = {
    age: 10, 
    'profile.contry': 'india'
};
```

Now I duplicate the `q` variable and remove key from a duplicate variable.

```
var duplicateQ = q;
delete duplicateQ['profile.contry']; // I have removed 'profile.country' from duplicateQ.

console.log(q); //Object { age: 10 }
console.log(duplicateQ); //Object { age: 10 }
```

Why are both the variables affected? How can I remove the property from only one of them?

Comment: `duplicateQ` is a reference to the original `q`. You need to clone the object. See the answer I marked as duplicate for more information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Technically, the OP is asking how to delete a property from a cloned object. While the "Cloning" is the problem, There's gotta be a better duplicate out there... (Not that I've found one yet)

Comment: True, although his method of deletion is correct. The problem he has is addressed by the dupe question.

Comment: I propose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object (Which I can apply, if you agree)

Comment: I agree - that one is more generic.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 11):

It's because `q` and `duplicateQ` refer to the same object. Thus, when you delete a property on one object, it effects both (since they both point to the same object).

You need to *copy*/*clone* the object.

In ES6, you can use the [`.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var q = {age:10, 'profile.contry': 'india'};
var duplicateQ = Object.assign({}, q);
delete duplicateQ['profile.contry'];
```

Output:

```
console.log(q);
// {age: 10, profile.contry: "india"}

console.log(duplicateQ);
// Object {age: 10}
```

Answer (score 7):

You aren't duplicating `q`, instead, you're copying a reference to  different variable.

Both `q` and `duplicateQ` point to the *same* object, the same location in your computer's memory.

In order to make this work, you're going to have to [clone the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), then you can delete (/ modify) individual properties on the separate variables.

A quick-and-dirty example:

```js
var a = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));

delete b.a;

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(a) + ' ' + JSON.stringify(b);
```